# Service should load data every hour

Tags: android, service, timer, timer-jobs

**Question**

---

I'm creating a service for my app, but there's probably pritty simple thing I can't realize. Better I say I don't know how to do this probably.

I'd like that my Service refreshs the data every hour if its between 6am and 6pm. How is this possible in a easy way which is also battery-efficient. If you have a some code snippets or a great tutorial for me I would be very happy, because I really like to learn this.

Best Regards

safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AlarmManager` to start the proceedings. First of all you need to check the current time that is current hour which you can get using `Calender.HOUR_OF_DAY`. Then you can check the current hour is between 6 to 18. If the condition satisfies you can refresh the data else you can cancel the Alarm and set it to the next period again.

Comment: next period? the problem is how can I tell my AlarmManger: "hey its now 6-18, reload the data now every hour...." That's where the problems start ...

Comment: by using `Calender.HOUR_OF_DAY` you will get the current hour and you can check the condition by that way.

Comment: so first allways check if its 1 2 3 etc. with Calender.HOUR_OF_DAY, afterwards if that condition is true it checks if the hour is between 6 to 18. Like that it could should work, but how would the code look like. I still don't get how to check if its now 1 2 or 3 etc.

Comment: but how can i loop that, sorry for doublepost... I can get the hour, than I check if its between 6-18o'clock, but how can I loop this????

Comment: loop is maintained by AlarmManager, you can just have a look at the AlarmManager example.

Comment: first off all the green tick for you, secound a question came up, when i have AlarmManger.setRepeating, it those allways when the criteria of it is allright send an intent? right? if yes i get how to do this now!

Comment: You can create a service and use `PendingIntent.getService()` to work around.

Answer (score 1):

Create an alarm which when fired refreshes your data and sets a new alarm one our (or 13 hours) in the future depending on current time (past 6pm). See here for more info on the alram manager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

you need a broadcast receiver that will fire the intent at 6 am to stop the service and at 6 pm to again start the service. By this way you can also improve battery consumtion.

Comment: the problem is, i have a reload button in my app, so the service has to run all the time, that he can reload the data.